# How to check if all " characters in a string are escaped

Tags: java, json

I haven't found anything online that could help me or maybe it is my knowledge in Regex expressions that hinder.

I would like to check if all " characters in a string are escaped. Take this string for example.

```
\"\"This is the first sentence\"
\"This is the second sentence\"
\"This is the third sentence\"\"
```

Comment: What about `\\"This is another sentence\\\\\\"`?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I don't know if that is sarcasm or if you are trying to help.

Comment: @jdphenix I just want to check if all " characters are preceded by a \.

Comment: as @immibis demonstrates, checking if all " are preceded by a \ is not the same as checking if all " are escaped.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard Oh dang. Now I see it, it should be "I want to check if all " characters are escaped in a string" Thank you for pointing that out. That last sentence should not be there.

Comment: @JakeMission: That is probably not the right approach to the problem you're trying to solve.  For example, how can you tell whether `\"` is escaped or not? (whether it's supposed to be `\\\"`)

Comment: @SLaks Now I am more confused on what I should do. I will check the first answer below.

Comment: @jdphenix's question was justified: for what do you need this?

Comment: @JakeMission I understand that much but what are you trying to do with the output? What motivated you to want this? Take a look at http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @jdphenix I just want to automate the checking of a certain part of a JSON script to ensure that that no " characters are left unescaped. Seems like attempting to parse it might be a good idea as it will return an error if it fails. WIll be checking out the second answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a leading `["` and trailing `"]` to the string, then attempt to parse it as JSON.  If everything is properly escaped there will be no parse errors.  You can use an online parser such as the one at http://json.parser.online.fr/ , if you want check a string from source, without running code.

Answer (score 0):

Following regex will match if any quotes are not escaped:

```
(^|[^\\])(\\\\)*"
```

Explanation:

```
(              <- first group
 ^             <- beginning of string
 |             <- or
 [^\\]         <- non-backslash character
)              <- first group
(\\\\)*        <- zero or more occurrences of exactly two backslashes
"              <- quote
```

In English: either at the beginning of the string, or after a non-backslash, match an even number of backslashes followed by a quote mark.

Comment: By the way, you can edit your own post if you want to change something about it. Click the `edit` link under the answer body.